# sscanf in c couldn't parse string

Tags: c, scanf

Please have a look into the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char driver_list[128] = {"123456,fariz,12345678,012-345-6789\n"
                        "234567,山田花子,23456789,012-345-6789\n"};

    int drvrId;
    char drvrName[32] = {0}, coma, userPsswrd[8];

    sscanf(driver_list, "%d%c%[^,]%c%[^,]", &drvrId, &coma, drvrName, &coma, userPsswrd);   
    printf("\n %d %c %s %s\n", drvrId, coma, drvrName, userPsswrd);

}
```

i am expecting the output like 
"123456 , fariz 12345678"

But i am getting 
"123456 ,  12345678"

when i printed each character in that array (drvrName) , first character was 
0x00(Null).so that no data printed.how could that possible first character 
became NULL?

please help.

Comment: I'm getting `123456 , fariz 12345678`. Followed by a stack corruption because `userPsswrd` doesn't account for the null-terminator.

Comment: userPsswrd[9] solved the issue.Previously when i printed each character in drvrName first character was null.